# Connecting Azure Event Grid to MQTTX

Tags: mqtt, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to connect my client in Azure Event Grid to MQTTX but it is not connecting.[image][image]

These are my clients which are not connecting. How should i fill the fields in MQTTX ? There is not much information available in the documentation either.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure documentation has exactly this scenario

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/mqtt-publish-and-subscribe-portal